# Copy data from one field to another on every row

Tags: sql, mysql

So I've got:

```
id    number
 1      0
 2      0
 3      0
```

Is there a sql statement to copy everything from id into number?

I'm about to write a php scrip to select, then update every row.  My SQL knowledge is pretty basic, but I'm sure there's a smart guy way to to do this:

Background:  The id used to be a number that was displayed in the app and was unique.  That number is no longer unique with some new features I'm adding--so I need to move it to a field that isn't unique while maintaining the integrity of the old.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use an update statement and reference the columns.  Just do the following:

```
update mytable set number = id
```

That sets number equal to id on each row.  Enjoy!

Comment: Wow, that's like ... white belt stuff.  I should probably get a book on sql and quit asking such simple questions ...

Comment: With around 10L records, this query is taking close to 25 secs, similarly with 1Crore records its taking even longer. Is there any faster way to do this? Like immediate copy with reference