# copy data from one field to another mysql mulitple rows

Tags: mysql

I want to copy data from one field to another mysql mulitple rows.

I've tried following but its not working for all and mysql even says "*returns more than 1 row*"

```
UPDATE agreement 
SET _date2 = (SELECT Concat(SUBSTRING(_date, 7), '-', SUBSTRING(_date, 4, 2), 
    '-', SUBSTRING(_date, 1, 2)) AS newdd FROM   agreementtemp);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy data from one field to another on every row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942161/copy-data-from-one-field-to-another-on-every-row)

Answer (score 10):

try

```
update `table_name` set  destination_field=source_field
```

Comment: This is a good answer. I like how to you specified destination and source field. It's hard to tell with the other answers which field is which and could result in data loss if a person isn't careful/knowledgable.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
update `tableName` set col1=col2
```

*For this to work both column should belong to same table and should be of same type.*

Answer (score 1):

You can update one field from another like this:

```
update mytable set field1=field2;
```

Comment: i want to do it in 3000 rows at a time

Comment: @wajid: it should work for all row. Does both column are of same type? are you using any where condition?

Comment: its not working for all mysql even says "returns more than 1 row"

Comment: update agreement set _date2 =(SELECT  
        concat(SUBSTRING(_date,7),'-',SUBSTRING(_date,4,2),'-',SUBSTRING(_date,1,2)) as newdd                    
FROM    agreementtemp);

Comment: @wajid: you can not do like this in your query sub-query(select con...) will return more than 1 row and make mysql confuse to select which newdd to take for update.

Comment: @wajid: You probably don't need a temp table at all, try: update agreement set _date2 =concat(SUBSTRING(_date,7),'-',SUBSTRING(_date,4,2),'-',SUBSTRING(_date,1,2));

Comment: @wajid: are you sure? what your query looks like now?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to update multiple tables and you can join on that table you can use the join syntax also in the UPDATE

UPDATE items,month SET items.price=month.price WHERE items.id=month.id;

or

```
UPDATE TABLE_1
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2
ON TABLE_1.COLUMN_1= TABLE_2.COLUMN_2 
SET TABLE_1.COLUMN = EXPR
WHERE TABLE_2.COLUMN2 IS NULL
```

In your case it would be

```
UPDATE agreement a1 
JOIN agreementtemp a2 
ON a1.id = a2.id 
SET a1._date2 = Concat(SUBSTRING(a2._date, 7), '-', SUBSTRING(a2._date, 4, 2) , '-', SUBSTRING(a2._date, 1, 2));
```

Comment: with insertion dont u think id's will get different