# Copy 1 column to another by mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have mysql database with following table...

```
| id | amount | tax |
+----+--------+-----+
|  1 | 500    |     |
+----+--------+-----+
|  2 | 100    |     |
+----+--------+-----+
```

I have to delete amount column but before doing that i want to shift all data of amount row from amount row to tax row. How can it be done using mysql query? Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy data from one field to another on every row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942161/copy-data-from-one-field-to-another-on-every-row)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

```
UPDATE mytable SET tax = amount
```

after you can remove it

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN amount;
```

Comment: With around 10L records, this query is taking close to 25 secs, similarly with 1Crore records its taking even longer. Is there any faster way to do this? Like immediate copy with reference

Answer (score 6):

```
update TABLE_NAME set tax=amount;
```

will do.

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE yTable SET tax = amount
```

Or to rename instead of copying (much faster):

```
ALTER yTable CHANGE amount tax YOURDATATYPE;
```

Delete tax before renaming.

Answer (score 1):

```
update your_table_name set tax=amount
```

you can delete the column data

```
UPDATE your_table_name SET amount = NULL WHERE amount is not null;
```

or you can delete column itself

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name DROP COLUMN amount
```

Comment: The OP want to delete the column too.